# grails required tag is not work at IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, grails, gsp, required

"required" property use in  tag is work correctly at chrome and firefox, but not in IE8 browser

in gsp file code:

```
<b> Name:  </b><g:textField name="name" id="textfield1" value="${name}"  required="true"　maxlength="30" type="hidden"></g:textField>
```

how can I let the require tag work success in IE8 and chrome or other browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `required` attribute of a form element is HTML5 which is not supported by older browsers such as IE8. This is not a limitation of Grails it's a limitation of the older browser.

You can read more about this attribute on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp). There you will also find the following compliance note.

> Note: The required attribute of the  tag is not supported in
>   Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Comment: thanks for your answer very much, how can i resolve this problem?

do you have any suggestions for change code or somethings that I should modify?

Comment: If you need client-side (e.g. in browser) validation you will need to either write your own, or use an existing plugin/library. For instance this is a very popular jquery plugin (I don't use it but many others do): http://jqueryvalidation.org/